# how to filling gap between patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image][image]I try to draw a custom curve consisting in a pattern that reproduces itself along the x axis. So I define a pattern with 4 nodes (P0-P3) and want to copy/paste the pattern with new nodes. the thing is that between each pattern I have a blank space that I want to fill.
I try to draw lines within the node but it is not really smooth.

Any idea?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\node[] (P0) at (0,1){};

\node[] (P1) at (2,2){};
\node[] (P2) at (5,-4){};
\node[] (P3) at (7,1){};
\node[] (P3b) at (7-0.1,1-0.05){};

\node[] (P4) at (9,2){};
\node[] (P5) at (12,-4.5){};
\node[] (P6) at (14,1){};

\node[] (P7) at (16,2){};
\node[] (P8) at (19,-4.5){};
\node[] (P9) at (21,1){};

\draw[line width = 8pt]
    (P0.north east) .. controls (P1.north east) and (P2.north east) ..
    (P3.south);

\draw[line width = 8pt]
    (P3b.north east) .. controls (P4.north east) and (P5.north east) ..
    (P6.center);

\draw[line width = 8pt]
    (P6.north east) .. controls (P7.north east) and (P8.north east) ..
    (P9.center);

\draw[line width = 8pt] (P3b.south) edge[] (P3.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

btw, i also tried to draw it with only one curve, but i don't know how to compute the nodes coordinates such as I get exactly the same pattern.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you after something like this:

[image]

You not draw a pattern but one line composed from three segments. This can be done by defining coordinates for beginning and end of segments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\coordinate (P0) at (0,1);
\coordinate (P1) at (2,2);
\coordinate (P2) at (5,-4);
\coordinate (P3) at (7,1);

\coordinate (P4) at (9,2);
\coordinate (P5) at (12,-4.5);
\coordinate (P6) at (14,1);

\coordinate (P7) at (16,2);
\coordinate (P8) at (19,-4.5);
\coordinate (P9) at (21,1);

\draw[line width = 8pt]
    (P0) .. controls (P1) and (P2) .. (P3)
         .. controls (P4) and (P5) .. (P6)
         .. controls (P7) and (P8) .. (P9);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok ok seems great!
thx!

Comment: @louis, you are welcome! BTW, are you still looking for better solution?  I'm just curious ;-)

Comment: not really if was a great solution you provided. I just slightly changed the coordinates of a few points to get slightly more smoothed curve at the maxima:

\coordinate (P3) at (7+1.25,1);
\coordinate (P6) at (14+1.25,1);
\coordinate (P9) at (21+1.25,1);

:)

Comment: @louis, it is not entirely clear what you after. You should look `decorations.pathmorphing` libraries, for `snake`. Described is Ti*k*Z documentation, page 641. In this library are also described other style of lines.

Comment: your answer was perfect ;) I didn't expect any supplementary comment as the task was done :)

Comment: @louis, if answer is perfect, you my consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer). By this people will be informed, that your problem is solved ...